# KnockOut.JS compare two arrays and remove unique value from second array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

I am working on Knockout.js.

```
var chosenFruit = ko.observableArray([]);
var allFruits   = ko.observableArray([]);

allFruits       =       [ "Apple" , "Bananna" , "Grapes" , "Oranges"]
chosenFruit     =       ["Apple" , "Bananna" , "kiwi"]
```

Now, Since "Kiwi" is not present in First Array(That means, in allFruits), I want to remove "Kiwi" from  second array (chosenFruit).

I want to compare both arrays and remove from second array - the value which is not present in first array.

That means , after comparison the second array should be :

```
chosenFruit   =        ["Apple" , "Bananna"]
```

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Thank You in Advance!

Comment: Please write what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method

```js
var allFruits = ["Apple", "Bananna", "Grapes", "Oranges"],
  chosenFruit = ["Apple", "Bananna", "kiwi"];

console.log(
  // iterate and filter out element
  chosenFruit.filter(function(v) {
    // check value present in array
    return allFruits.indexOf(v) > -1;
  })
)
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :** If you want to keep the reference use **[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** for removing the element.

```js
var allFruits = ["Apple", "Bananna", "Grapes", "Oranges"],
  chosenFruit = ["Apple", "Bananna", "kiwi"];
// store length for iterating
var i = chosenFruit.length;

// iterate upto `0`
while (i--) {
  // check value exist in array
  if (allFruits.indexOf(chosenFruit[i]) == -1) {
    // if not present then remove it
    chosenFruit.splice(i, 1);
  }
}


console.log(chosenFruit);
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :**
With knockout do something like this using **[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** which generates a new filtered array.

```js
var chosenFruit = ko.observableArray(["Apple", "Bananna", "Grapes", "Oranges"]);
var allFruits = ko.observableArray(["Apple", "Bananna", "kiwi"]);

console.log(
  chosenFruit().filter(function(v) {
    return allFruits().indexOf(v) > -1;
  })
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

---

**UPDATE 3 :** If you want to update the observableArray then use [`remove()`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#remove-and-removeall) method with callback function.

```js
var chosenFruit = ko.observableArray(["Apple", "Bananna", "Grapes", "Oranges"]);
var allFruits = ko.observableArray(["Apple", "Bananna", "kiwi"]);

allFruits.remove(function(v) {
  return chosenFruit().indexOf(v) == -1;
});

console.log(allFruits())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are not removing anything from the `chosenFruit` array.

Comment: @Redu : just assigning returning value will do the trick `chosenFruit = chosenFruit.filter(function(v) {
    return allFruits.indexOf(v) > -1;
  })` ..... but it will destroy the reference, I don't think refernce in necessary here

Comment: No it will not do the trick. If you do so any array that refers to `chosenFruit` will still be showing ["Apple", "Bananna", "kiwi"]. There references will be lost due to the assignment operator (`=`).

Comment: @user2598808 : any error ? you need to assign the returned value `chosenFruit = chosenFruit.filter(function(v) {
    return allFruits.indexOf(v) > -1;
  })`

Comment: @Redu : yes it will destroy the reference.... but i don't think reference is necessary here

Comment: Array returned is always empty in console

Comment: Thank You, I will check your updated response and try it out. This is my fiddle, just created one : https://jsfiddle.net/9focy8nr/ Thanks again !

Comment: Thank You ! When I implement the same in my project , I am getting this error : Uncaught TypeError: chosenFruit.filter is not a function

Comment: @user2598808 which browser are you using? also check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill ...... arew you sure `chosenFruit` is an array ?

Comment: Its an Observable Array , I am using KnockOut.JS hence I have declared as  ko.observableArray([]);

Comment: Yes last one looks better i also modified to handle multiple elements.

Comment: @user2598808 :  then you need to use `ko.utils.arrayFilter`

Comment: @Pranav I have no Idea how to use ko.utils.arrayFilter. I am new to this. I will google search and learn. If you have any idea please suggest . Thank You so much !

Comment: @user2598808 : I'm not familiar with knockout... Anyway check the last update

Comment: Thank You! Unfortunately, I am still struggling with this piece. Since I am new to KO, I think I should first learn the subject. Thanks Again

Comment: Will this completely update the chosenFruit() array? if so, Can i assign the result into new array? Thank You for all your help with this!

Comment: @user2598808 : added another method which updates the observable array

Comment: Sure, I will check it. We need to remove unique value from chosenFruit() and add that into an array. Also, we need to make sure that chosenFruit and allFruits stay uneffected. I hope this works for me.

Comment: @user2598808 : after some googling I got the documentation.... http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks a ton !

Comment: @user2598808 : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows by locating and deleting the item that shouldn't be in the `chosenFruits` array.;

```js
allFruits   = [ "Apple" , "Bananna" , "Grapes" , "Oranges"],
chosenFruit = ["Apple" , "Bananna" , "Kiwi", "Melon", "Cockroach"];
  discarded = chosenFruit.reduceRight((p,c,i,a) => !allFruits.includes(c) ? p.concat(a.splice(i,1)) : p,[]);
                                                                  
console.log(chosenFruit);
console.log(discarded);
```

With conventional functions;

```js
allFruits   = [ "Apple" , "Bananna" , "Grapes" , "Oranges"],
chosenFruit = ["Apple" , "Bananna" , "Kiwi", "Melon", "Cockroach"];
  discarded = chosenFruit.reduceRight(function(p,c,i,a){
                                        return allFruits.indexOf(c) === -1 ? p.concat(a.splice(i,1))
                                                                           : p;
                                      },[]);
                                                                  
console.log(chosenFruit);
console.log(discarded);
```

Comment: I am sorry if this is a silly question but What is this symbol "=> "? I am trying to achieve this in a JS File using KnockOut.JS.

Comment: @user2598808 ES6 arrow function

Comment: @user2598808 that's a function definition called arrow functions. I will give a modified version of the above snippet in conventional function definitions.

Comment: @Redu Thank You so much for your response. Please suggest can we use that arrow in JavaScript File.

Comment: @user2598808 If your target environment complies with ES6 standards of JS you can safely use arrows.

Comment: @Redu :  this will only removes single element ... if there is multiple element ???

Comment: @user2598808 Now it should do with multiple elements by keeping the references safe and will also return a discarded array as well.

Comment: @Redu , Thank You! I am checking this in my code now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($(["Apple" , "Bananna" , "kiwi"]).filter([ "Apple" , "Bananna" , "Grapes" , "Oranges"]).get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank You @Laurianti , I need to use KnockOut.JS